# Random Entry that has a category_id equal to one provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to get a random database entry (Video) that has a category_id equal to one I provide.

The code I'm currently using to get random Videos,

```
def self.random()
  @count = self.count()
  self.find(:first, :offset => rand(count))
end
```

This code works perfectly for finding a random video, however I need to constrain it to a video that has the :category_id that I provide.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be something like this

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
@category.videos[rand(count)]
```

I'm a rails noob, so I don't know, maybe there is a more efficient way to do this

Comment: Wow! Sometimes I forget about some of the very simple solutions that Ruby and Rails offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your videos_controller.rb

```
def random_video
    category_id = params[:category_id] #or however you are getting the id
    @video = Video.find(:random, :conditions => ['category_id=?', category_id])
    render :action => 'show'
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Sam, I wasn't very clear in what I was trying to do. (I've edited my post). Basically what I need is to find a random Video that has the :category_id that I provide, not a random category.